# Flash CS3 error: fl.getDocumentDOM() has no properties

Tags: flash, flash-cs3

What causes the publish error:
"fl.getDocumentDOM() has no properties" ?

The error occurs only when using the "Test Project" button in the project pane. It doesn't cause the publish to fail, it's just annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when you don't have any flash documents open. You can't publish 'headless' in flash cs3 without throwing an error (albeit benign).

Answer (score 0):

I have a friendly solution:

```
var myDocument = fl.getDocumentDom() || false;
if(!myDocument){
  alert("Please open at least one document");
}
```

Comment: Right ... is that javascript? Where does that go?